# Recursion with '|' or '||' operator not returning false in base case

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, bitwise-operators

So I'm looking at recursion method I'm using to solve code challenge.   I believe this might be just a misunderstanding on my part.  Here is the recursive function.

```
    public static boolean canSum(int[] arr, int max)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        if(max == 0) return true;
        if(arr.length == 0) return false;
        else return canSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), max) | canSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), max-arr[0]);
    }
```

Now it works in that it will eventually give me true or false if the integers in my Array in any combination will give me the max value I'm looking for, or it will return false.  What I don't understand is if I `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)` I can see my array being reduced to 0 length and if I debug it appears to hit the line `if(arr.length == 0) return false;`.  So why does the function not break there and return false.  This recursive function keeps going essentially.  Here is the console arrays I'm seeing for this use case

```
System.out.println(canSum(new int[]{3,5,-1,8}, 12));
```

Output:

```
[-1, 3, 5, 8]
[3, 5, 8]
[5, 8]
[8]
[]
[]
[8]
[]
[]
[5, 8]
[8]
[]
[]
[8]
[]
[]
[3, 5, 8]
[5, 8]
[8]
[]
[]
[8]
[]
[]
[5, 8]
[8]
[]
[]
[8]
[]
[]
true
```

I understand how the Arrays.copyOfRange keeps removing an index of the array but I guess I'm not understanding the operator | (I think || works as well) and why I need to `max=arr[0]`.  Based on debug, it looks like `canSum(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), max-arr[0])` runs when my arr.length = 0.  So is the OR really like ternary here for recursive function call?  I'm not sure how 'return recurseFunct(n-1, m) | recurseFunct (n-1, m-n[0])' works in this scenario exactly.  It seems really handy and I would like to understand it better.

****** Adding this video as it supports the accepted answer *******

You can visually see the stack that is being used in this recurse on the left hand side of the debugger.  The size of the stack varies for a bit until it finally empties completely.  Once empty i will return true or false in the recursive function at that point.  This was good learning experience for me.  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `|` is not short-circuiting, by design. Is there are reason you didn't use `||`?

Comment: Both work.  I could use either operator in this solution.  You are correct.   Actually || is maybe little quicker but doesn't help with my confusion either way.  :)

Comment: "*So why does the function not break there and return false*" Because you are using logical OR. `X || Y` = X **or** Y may be true. So X may be false (i.e. the breakpoint that you hit), but just because it is doesn't mean that Y isn't true, making the whole expression resolve to true.

Comment: *"I'm not understanding the bit operator `|`"* --- That is not a bit operator. Well, it *can* be a [Integer Bitwise Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1), but since the operands are `boolean` values, not integer numbers, it's a [Boolean Logical Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).

Comment: Sorry for incorrect usage of bit operator term.  For simplicity sake I updated to just use term 'Operator' in the post.   Thanks for correcting @Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I debug it appears to hit the line if(arr.length == 0) return
>   false;. So why does the function not break there and return false.
>   This recursive function keeps going essentially.

The sequence of the function call is like below. (index in a bracket).

```
                 call(0)
                /       \
        call(1)     ||     call(4)
        /     \             /    \
    call(2) || call(3)  call(5) || call(6)  
    /\          /\      /\          /\
   /  \        /  \    /  \        /  \
```

The functions call will be stored in a stack like below

```
call(2)
call(1)
call(0)
```

if call(2) returns false, it will pop call(2) from the stack and come back to call(1) and push call(3) to stack.

```
call(3)
call(1)
call(0)
```

if call(3) returns false, it will pop call(3) from stack, come back to call(1), call(1) will return (call(2) || call(3)),pop call(1) from stack, come back to call(0) and push call(4).

so even if any function call returns false, there are a remaining bunch of calls to be performed and so

> recursive function keeps going essentially

Comment: Really great answer.  Thank you! added to original post a visualization to help others if they find this post.

Comment: To be clear, I thought I had written a recursive function.  But apparently I have a binary tree here as well?  If so, are all recursive functions binary trees and are they all balanced like this one?

Comment: No, because here for each function call we are dealing with 2 child function call. f(a) = f(a-1) || f(a-2) || f(a-3) in this case we'll have 3 function call for each parent function call.